# Speeding up ODEINT stiff example

Tags: ode, c++

I am trying the implement the following odeint solver example but my differential equations are different.

https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2/blob/master/examples/stiff_system.cpp

The system I have is stiff so the rosenbrock method is a good fit for that. However, the solution process is really slow, often taking 2 million steps to reach t = 2.5s.

Is there any way to tweak the adaptive stepping settings and see what steps are being taken by the solver? I haven't been able to find a good documentation for this, the only one I found is

http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/doc/boost_numeric_odeint/tutorial/stiff_systems.html

If there is a way to speed it up without tweaking the stepping, that would work as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost_numeric_odeint/odeint_in_detail/steppers.html) and [this spot in the code](https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2/blob/master/include/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/rosenbrock4_controller.hpp#L148) show that it is doing Gustafsson acceleration. That's usually a good technique and is advocated by Hairer. I have found in my own tests that actually PI-controllers work surprisingly well with high order Rosenbrock methods, but YMMV. It's probably problem and tableau dependent. But anyways, that's the spot in the code you'd modify.

But I do want to address one other thing.

> The system I have is stiff so the rosenbrock method is a good fit for that.

Not necessarily, I wouldn't not blindly say this at all. The Rosenbrock methods tend to be good for stiff equations when you are trying to solve for error less than $\approx10^{-6}$ and your system of equations is not sufficiently large (I'll point to [Hairer II](https://www.google.com/search?q=hairer+solving+ordinary+differential+equations+ii&oq=hairer+solving+ord&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.4835j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), the [DiffEqBenchmarks](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DiffEqBenchmarks.jl), and lots of other currently unpublished benchmarks which all pretty much say the same thing). But then again, multistep methods can still "sneak a win" if the system is smooth enough every one in awhile, so it's not a hard-fast rule. If you really want to be sure what's good for your problem, I would recommend solving a small part of your real equation using some suite that has easy access to Radau, both high and low order Rosenbrock, a BDF, and optionally high and low order (E)SDIRK methods since these tend to do the best in various regimes. You should also generate a reference solution since comparing timings without comparing error is never a good idea (many times the faster one can just have a higher error), which is why work-precision diagrams are a good tool if you want to do this comparison easily. [This example in the DiffEqBenchmarks](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DiffEqBenchmarks.jl/blob/master/StiffODE/ROBER.ipynb) shows an easy way to run such a test, though you can also setup something similar with MATLAB or with wrappers to Hairer's solver suite for example to see similar results (but with some missing methods in each case).